# Creading a CenttOS 7 compatible encrypted password in Windows

Tags: centos, windows, users, password

**How do I create a `crypt(3)` encrypted password in a Windows DevBox that a remote CentOS 7 server can interpret successfully when creating a new user account via the following `useradd` command in a bash script?**

```
useradd -u 12345 -g users -d /home/username -s /bin/bash -p '$1$NNfXfoym$Eos.OG6sFMGE8U6ImwBqT1' username
```

For testing purposes, let's assume that the cleartext version of the password should be `Whirlpool_Sauna_Soap`

When I `man useradd`, I get the following for `-p`

```
   -p, --password PASSWORD
       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to
       disable the password.

       Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or
       encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

       You should make sure the password respects the system's password
       policy.
```

I am using putty to log in to the remote CentOS 7 server from a Windows DevBox.  I would like to `scp` the file that contains the script from the Windows DevBox to the remote CentOS 7 server, and then run the script via SSH connection.

Comment: You need to run a program that can call a compatible crypt library routine. You could write such a thing in`C`, but `python` has https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html and perl also does. So the question you need to answer is what tools you have on your Windows DevBox? Would you accept a solution that uses ssh to run a command on your CentOS box, and if so what do you have available on that box? Could you use `useradd` roo create the account without setting the password and then use `chpasswd` to set it?

Answer (score 1):

I also used a script to generate users like this:

`useradd -u 12345 -g users -d /home/username -s /bin/bash -p '$(openssl passwd -1 Whirlpool_Sauna_Soap)' username`

Comment: Probably better to leave off the `-1` as the OP was asking for crypt(3) compatible, although I agree that these probably should not be used.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to answer. I guess I feel a little unsatisfied putting the password in clear text like that. ... I also have not tested this to see if it is crypt(3) compatible.

Comment: Well... You don't need to. You can just create the password with this command and then put the hash in the script...